# Preenchimento de campo input

Tags: javascript, html

Boa tarde pessoal, é o seguinte, tenho dois campos input em um formulário, no primeiro input insiro um valor, logo depois clico em calcular e o segundo input é preenchido com valor que é calculado pela multiplicação do valor recebido no primeiro input por 2,40. até aí tudo certo, está funcionando legal, porém gostaria que o segundo input fosse preenchido logo quando o primeiro perdesse o focu sem a necessidade de clicar no botão calcular. segue o código e o exemplo

```js
function calcularUFM(){
 var formulario = document.getElementById("formulario");
 
 var valor_ufm = +formulario.valor_ufm.value;
 
 var reais = (valor_ufm * 2.40);

 formulario.reais.value = reais.toFixed(2);
 
}
```

```html
<html>
<head>
  <title></title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/estiloImc.css" type="text/css" media="all">
  <script type="text/javascript" src="js/scriptUfm.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
  <form id="formulario">
    <fieldset>
      <legend>CACULADORA UFM / REIAIS</legend>

      <label for="valor_ufm">VALOR EM UFM</label>
      <input type="text" name="valor_ufm" /><br /><br />

      <label for="reais"></label>
      <input type="text" name="reais" disabled="disabled" /><br /><br />

      <a href="#" onclick="calcularUFM();">calcular</a>
    </fieldset>
  </form>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pode aplicar um `onblur` no campo chamando a função:

```
formulario.valor_ufm.onblur = calcularUFM;
```

Ou direto no elemento:

```
<input type="text" name="valor_ufm" onblur="calcularUFM()" />
```

Comment: Obrigado Sam, deu certo ,valeu! usei a segunda opção

Comment: De nada amigo. Saiba como agradecer neste link -> [tour]